# export pdf from maatwebsite/excel has error

Tags: laravel

i using from laravel 8 and [maatwebsite/excel](https://laravel-excel.com/) package for export data from table to pdf.

in the route:

```
Route::get('users/export', [UserController::class,"export"]);
```

i have a UserExport class

```
 <?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

in the UserController

```
    public function export()
    {
        return (new UsersExport)->download('users.pdf', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::MPDF);
    }
```

i have a error

Call to undefined method App\Exports\UsersExport::download()

Comment: is mpdf installed along in your project?

Comment: @bhucho yes sir.  i installed this.